# Return elements of a list up to first even

Tags: python

I am writing a function that will return the elements of a list up to the first even number in said list.

```
def up_to_even(list):
    new_list = []
    for num in list:
        if num % 2 != 0:
            new_list.append(num)
        else: 
            return new_list
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The function works fine here. Did you remember to call it?

Comment: Yes, now it is working. I'm not really sure what was going on. As a follow up, how would I modify this code to use a "while" loop instead of an "if" loop?

Comment: What should it return when there are no even numbers?  Currently it returns `None`.

Comment: You might consider using [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current function works fine. It stops adding elements to the resulting list when an even number is found.

However, using a `for` loop here is *controlled iteration*, which is only needed if you want to check every element in the list. This is why your current function needs to have a special `else` case to specially break out of the loop and return the resulting list.

Since you don't know when you'll encounter an even number, you can use a `while` loop instead, also known as *uncontrolled iteration*.

Here is an example:

```
lst = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]

i = 0
result = []
while lst[i] % 2 != 0:
    result.append(lst[i])
    i += 1

print(result)
# [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Remember that you could always use [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to also do this:

```
import itertools

lst = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]

result = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x : x % 2 != 0, lst))

print(result)
# [1, 3, 5, 7]
```

**Note:** Using [`lambda`](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) here just creates an anonymous function on the spot. If you don't wish to use this, you can create your own helper function instead:

```
def evens(x):
    return x % 2 != 0
```

And call `itertools.takewhile()` in just the same way:

```
result = list(itertools.takewhile(evens, lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't take into account the case when there are no even number in the list, in which case it never get to the `else` and therefore no list is returned, to fix it just add a return at the end of the funtion

```
def up_to_even(lst):
    new_list = []
    for num in lst:
        if num % 2 != 0:
            new_list.append(num)
        else: 
            return new_list # or use break
    return new_list
```

here some tests

```
>>> up_to_even([1,3,4])
[1, 3]
>>> up_to_even([1,3,4,5])
[1, 3]
>>> up_to_even([1,3,41,5])
[1, 3, 41, 5]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is returning 'None' when there is no 'even' so here is updated version of your code in few lines :

if the data is:

```
a=[1,3,5,7,9,2,33,77]
```

code :

```
def up_to_even(list_1):
    new_list=[]
    for i in list_1:
        if i%2!=0:
            new_list.append(i)
        else:
            break
    return new_list
print(up_to_even(a))
```

output:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

**P.S : Don't use variable name as 'list' , 'list' is a keyword in python.**

Answer (score 0):

in python3

```
form itertools import takewhile

def up_to_even(lst): 
  return list(takewhile(lambda x: x%2, lst)
```